# Регистрация пользователей django

Tags: python, html, django

На сайте работает система контроля пользователей django-allauth. Проблемы со страницой регистрации.
Я не могу использовать форму, получаемую страницей регистрации по умолчанию, так как в неё очень сложно внедрить мои стили. Поэтому я пишу свою, код которой представлен ниже. Мне нужно, чтобы если не удалось зарегестрировать пользователя, он мог видеть проблему. Пока я использую {% if form.errors %}, но он не говорит, какая именно ошибка возникла. Как мне выводить причину отклонения регистрации более конкретно?

signup.html

```
    {% if form.errors %}
        <center>
            <p>
                Не удалось зарегестрировать пользователя. Либо пользователь с таким логином уже существует, либо
                введённые вами пароли не совпадают.
            </p>
        </center>
    {% endif %}
    <div id="form-margin">
        <form action="{% url 'account_signup' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <center>
                <div class="g">
                    <input type="text" class="text" name="username" autocomplete="off" id="login_id" required>
                    <label class="placeholder" for="login_id">Логин</label>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="g">
                    <input type="password" class="text" name="password1" id="password1_id" required>
                    <label class="placeholder" for="password1_id">Пароль</label>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="g">
                    <input type="password" class="text  " name="password2" autocomplete="off" id="password2_id" required>
                    <label class="placeholder" for="password2_id">Повторите</label>
                    <span class="bar"></span>
                </div>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit">
                <h3>
                    Уже есть аккаунт? <br><br><a href="{% url 'login' %}">Войдите</a>.
                </h3>
            </center>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ты в шаблоне проверяешь `{% if form.errors %}`, в нем находится словарь, в котором, хранится информация об ошибках формы в формате:

```
{
    'имя_поля_1': ['ошибка 1', 'ошибка 2', ...],
    'имя_поля_2': ['ошибка 1', 'ошибка 2', ...],
}
```

выведи содержимое этого словаря пользователю. Подробней в официальной [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.errors).
Так же нужно не забыть о том, что есть еще `non_field_errors`